# Spring Data MongoDb: is there possibility to define custom Criteria?

Tags: java, spring-data-mongodb

I have simple interface with one method:

```
 Criteria toCriteria(String key, String value)
```

And next I'd like to have next implementation

```
public class EqExpression implements Expression
{

     @Override
     public Criteria toCriteria(String key, String value)
     {
        return Criteria.where(key).eq(Pattern.compile(value));
     }
}

}
```

but there isn't **$eq** operator. So my questions:

- Why `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria` doesn't have such operator?
- Is there a way to implement custom Criteria implementation or is there any workaround?
- For me it would be good to have code like

  ```
   @Override
   public Criteria toCriteria(String key, String value)
   {
      //return new BasicDBObject(key, new BasicDBObject("$eq", value)) converted to Criteria
   }
  ```

In general, my purpose is to implement rest query language and for each operation like `gt`, `lt` I have specific implementation of `Expression` interface.

Request may looks like `name=John&age>20`

I am building whole query using next code:

```
List<Criteria> criterias = new ArrayList<Criteria>();
...
while (matcher.find())
    {
        String key = matcher.group(1);
        String operator = matcher.group(2);
        String value = matcher.group(3);
        // get from map appropriate implementation
        criterias.add(expressions.get(operator).toCriteria(key, value));
    }
```

May be you have any suggestions how to implement it more elegant

Comment: docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/Criteria.html. `is(Object o)` is your equality operator.

Comment: @Veeram `is` generates query `{ "name" : "John"}`  but I need `{"name": {"$eq": "John"}}`

Comment: it's the same. It's implicit equals. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/. Check the examples.

Comment: @Veeram ohh, thanks a lot, I got it! so does Criteria cover all mongo operations and there isn't need in defining custom ones, yep?

Comment: No worries. Not for the case you mentioned.

Comment: @Veeram hah, ok, but in general?

Comment: You may need it in cases spring doesn't support the latest mongo version and you can still upgrade to mongo  driver to latest version while keeping the same spring mongo db version and then create expression to use operator from latest mongo version that you want to use.

Comment: @Veeram how spring mongo db supports creating new expressions, could you provide any links?

Answer (score 0):

using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60459200/1285983), I was able to create simple $eq Criteria

```
private Criteria getEqCriteria(String value)
{
    // hack Criteria, because new Criteria().is(value) not working!
    Criteria c = new Criteria();
    try
    {
        Field _criteria = c.getClass().getDeclaredField("criteria");
        _criteria.setAccessible(true);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        LinkedHashMap<String, Object> criteria = (LinkedHashMap<String, Object>) _criteria.get(c);
        criteria.put("$eq", value);
        Field _criteriaChain = c.getClass().getDeclaredField("criteriaChain");
        _criteriaChain.setAccessible(true);

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Criteria> criteriaChain = (List<Criteria>) _criteriaChain.get(c);
        criteriaChain.add(c);
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Ignore
    }
    return c;
}
```