# Spring data Mongo db Convert from Document to Criteria

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

So from a `Criteria` we have `getCriteriaObject` which returns `Document` and then you are able to do some operations on the document, but then I wanna use the results by converting back to a `Criteria`, I couldn't really find how.

Of course let's take in consideration complex `Criteria` with multiple operators etc. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the definition of a `Criteria` and what is the definition of `Document`?  What version of the MongoDB driver are you using. Also, what version of MongoDB database are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Short answer: No

`Criteria` has [Querydsl](http://www.querydsl.com/)-Like syntax which allows the generation of *type-safe* queries. Reading from `Document` may introduce *MongoDB incompatible commands or syntax* for the current MongoDB version.

### Long answer: Yes

We can implement **walkaround** with [Java reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)#Java) to add Document `key:value` into Criteria `private` fields.
**Warning:** You assume your `Document` has compatible operators with correct syntax.

Add this helper method into your class ([souce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196192/how-to-read-the-value-of-a-private-field-from-a-different-class-in-java)):

```
public static Criteria from(Document document) {
    Criteria c = new Criteria();

    try {

        Field _criteria = c.getClass().getDeclaredField("criteria");
        _criteria.setAccessible(true);

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        LinkedHashMap<String, Object> criteria = (LinkedHashMap<String, Object>) _criteria.get(c);

        for (Entry<String, Object> set : document.entrySet()) {
            criteria.put(set.getKey(), set.getValue());
        }

        Field _criteriaChain = c.getClass().getDeclaredField("criteriaChain");
        _criteriaChain.setAccessible(true);

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Criteria> criteriaChain = (List<Criteria>) _criteriaChain.get(c);
        criteriaChain.add(c);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Ignore
    }

    return c;
}
```

---

Now create new instance for `Criteria` from `Document`:

```
Criteria newCriteria = from(criteria.getCriteriaObject());

//You have full-compatible Criteria instance
newCriteria.and("foobar").elemMatch(Criteria.where("field").is("value"));
```